# RegEx on this 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM to get 1/1/0001

Tags: c#, regex

Input is 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM. After the regex I would like out put to be 1/1/0001

can't get the regex to working. Any idea>

forgot to post my failed regex

```
([^\s]+)
```

By the way, I am looking for Date conversion. String to string conversion. The above results in 3 words seperated by ;

Comment: I would be inclined to parse as a `DateTime` and then `ToString()` the date...

Comment: @Russ, why not simply splitting the string on whitespace, then?

Comment: There are many different ways to go about this (string split, regex, parsing via `DateTime` and more). However, we don't understand the exact requirements after seeing only a single example, we don't know how you are to use the result and most importantly, you have not shown any of your efforts to get to an answer yourself.

Comment: The regular expression line you posted wouldn't even compile - and why did you try that pattern?

Comment: @Oded because Copy/Paste is bad (:

Comment: ([^\s]+) tried this. result is 3 string seperated by ;

Comment: @torres Doesn't this <^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}> work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your particular case the RegEx would be:

```
^\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}
```

** This is general regex string. You have to escape backslashes in C#/JavaScript etc.

This will match 1/1/0001 or 01/01/0001 etc.
But will also match 56/56/9999! So after getting the date part you should do sanity checks.

But I would prefer to create DateTime object and to get the date part using DateTime's members.

**UPDATE**

If you use ([^\s]+) then you get three capturing groups:

- 1/1/0001
- 12:00:00
- AM

So you have to extract the first capturing group, usually with index 1:

```
var datePart = matchObj.Groups[1].Value // Should be "1/1/0001"
```

Comment: this works. What would the syntax to get all the words in a string after the first space. For example, bobs nice house. So the result should be " nice house" without the quote.

Comment: That's another question that you should ask ;) But please take time to read info/examples here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: \s(.*) this is the asnwer.

Comment: @torres be aware of Patashu's comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15987800/1022219

Answer (score 0):

You can create DateTime object from this string, after it - to ise built in functions, like ToShortDate()

Answer (score 0):

```
string Date = "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM";
string NewDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Date).ToShortDateString(); //note the output will be relate to local datetime format
string NewDate2 = Date.Substring(0, Date.IndexOf(' '));
```

Convert it to `DateTime` first, and then back to string by using `ToShortDateString()` or remove everything that is after the space char.

Answer (score 0):

This will be the regex for getting date from your input

```
"\\d{1}-\\d{1}-\\d{4}"
```

Comment: This does not match dates like 12/31/2012 or 31/12/2012. Also the input does not contain dashes, but forward slashes.

Comment: Oh thanks for you correction i didnt read the format correctly.