# Regex to get everything after the first space

Tags: c#, regex, string

What would the syntax to get all the words in a string after the first space. For example, bobs nice house. So the result should be " nice house" without the quote.

`([^\s]+)` gives me all 3 words seperated by ;

`,[\s\S]*$ >` not compiling.

Answer (score 31):

I was really looking shortest possible code. following did the job. thanks guys

```
\s(.*)
```

Comment: As long as you're aware that `\s` matches all white space, not just spaces

Answer (score 7):

I think it should be done this way:

```
[^ ]* (.*)
```

It allows 0 or more elements that are not a space, than a single space and selects whatever comes after that space.

***C# usage***

```
var input = "bobs nice house";

var afterSpace = Regex.Match(input, "[^ ]* (.*)").Groups[1].Value;
```

`afterSpace` is `"nice house"`.

To get that first space as well in result string change expression to `[^ ]*( .*)`

***No regex solution***

```
var afterSpace = input.Substring(input.IndexOf(' '));
```

Comment: this gives same as input string

Comment: I'm asking about c# code, not regex you've used in it. Could you edit your question and show it there, please?

Comment: @torres the result is stored in the first capturing group (index 1). You can take it this way: matchObj.Groups[1].Value

Answer (score 2):

*Actually*, you don't need to use regex for that process. You just need to use [`String.Split()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.string.split.aspx) method like this;

```
string s = "bobs nice house";
string[] s1 = s.Split(' ');
for(int i = 1; i < s1.Length; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(s1[i]);
```

Output will be;

```
nice
house
```

Here is a [`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/VwFYAD).

Answer (score 2):

use `/(?<=\s).*/g` to find string after first space.run snippet check

```js
str="first second third forth fifth";
str=str.match(/(?<=\s).*/g)
console.log(str);
```