# How to select everything after the 1st space regex

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this simple little string "Wed 09 Sept", and I'd like to select "09 Sept"

This will take everything from the 1st space:

\s(.*) (as from [Regex to get everything after the first space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987650/regex-to-get-everything-after-the-first-space))

But it comes with the space, and i'd like to get rid of that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the first capture group of that regular expression:

```
"Wed 09 Sept" =~ /\s(.*)/ 
selection     = $1
# => "09 Sept"
```

The [`=~`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-3D-7E)
operator matches a pattern against a string. The `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc. variables refer to capture groups.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what a capture group is or how to implement that

Comment: It's already in the regular expression you posted. More information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: This is what I'm looking for I think. What is that "=~" sign? Also, the $ sign is a global variable right? What is happening in this code?

Comment: If you're doing this in a method you can write it like this `selection[/\s(.*)/][$1]`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `\K` to discard the previously matched characters.

```
^\S*\s\K.*
```

OR

```
^\S* \K.*
```

OR

```
\s\K.*
```

OR

```
 \K.*
```

`\S*` matches zero or more non-space characters and `\s+` matches one or more spaces. `\K` discards the previously matched characters that from being printed out at the final. Now `.*` would match all the remaining characters. This would be printed at the final.

[DEMO 1](http://www.rubular.com/r/WCzihSnI0p)  [DEMO 2](http://www.rubular.com/r/S85Ev0w8ry)

Answer (score 0):

Group the first space and the rest `/(\s)(.*)/`, like:

```
pry(main)> m = /(?'first'\s)(?'rest'.*)/.match 'Wed 09 Sept'
=> #<MatchData " 09 Sept" first:" " rest:"09 Sept">
pry(main)> m[:rest]
=> "09 Sept"
```